# How to capture only one line from a console process?

Tags: c#, console

I have an application that starts and then reads the standard output of a console process. In that console process I call some DLL files which write to the console..but I dont want to capture those messages, I just want to capture an output string they send.

I tried doing :

```
verboseMethod(); //method writting things into the console

output = dllMethod(); //method returning what I want

Console.Clear();
Console.Out.Write(output)
```

I am doing this so I believe I am reading everything before Console.Clear() executes :

```
exeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
                string errString = exeProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Can you give me an alternative to this? Like wait until last output message is given or something of the sort?

**EDIT**

I believe something like this would help (if it exists)..can I tell the console not to redirect the output or not to write anything at a certain point and then allow it to write once again somewhere else in the code? Like :

```
Console.CloseBuffer();

Console.OpenBuffer();
```

Comment: What you can do is redirect the output to a stream, and then stop reading ("capturing") from that stream once you have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using asychronous redirect of output, and turn on and off 'EnableRaisingEvents' so you are only capturing between the execution you want. Use BeginOutputReadLine() and CancelOutputRead() to start/stop console reading.

```
        var myOutput = new StringBuilder();
        var myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path, command);
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        myProcess.OutputDataReceived += (object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.Data != null)
            {
                myOutput.AppendLine(e.Data);
            }
        };

        myProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.Data != null)
            {
                myOutput.AppendLine(e.Data);
            }
        };
        myProcess.Start();

        verboseMethod();

        //Start Capture here!
        myProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
        myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

        dllMethod();
```